# How can I stop IE 11/Win7 from removing ".exe" from downloade files?

Tags: javascript, html, installation

I have an application which I have created an installer for. I have signed the application with a certificate. With every browser/windows combination I have tried downloading the installer works fine, except Windows 7 IE 11.

This combination strips the .exe off of the file. If I add the .exe back, the installer works fine. The file resides on the web server and I cause the download using the following JS;

```
function processDownload(inInstalLink, ApplicationName)
{
    if (confirm("Download "+ ApplicationName + " application?"))
    {
        var intRandom =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
        window.location = inInstalLink + "?tempID=" + intRandom; //Launch alternative, typically app download.
    }
}
```

I call the javascript above as follows;

```
 processDownload("MyInstaller.exe", "My Fun Application")
```

I have read about content disposition tags, but am at a loss on how to implement them here, and not sure if they would solve the problem. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Try this: ` window.location = inInstalLink + "?tempID=" + intRandom + ".exe"` it seems to be a known issue with IE 11 on Windows 7 and download URLs with query strings.

Comment: If I add the code suggested this would add a ".exe" to a parameter, which doesn't seem reasonable. I modified the question adding how I call the function processDownload, perhaps this will make things clearer.

Comment: That code just adds a string to the query string appended to the end of your random number.

I was passing on a solution that other developers with the exact same problem was able to use to bypass an issue with a 7 year old soon to be abandoned browser. https://github.com/atom/atom.io/issues/51

Hacks for IE are usually unreasonable, but are the price that you pay to service outdated IE browsers.

Comment: Un-F***ing-believable. Thanks for your help. Make it an answer, and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a common problem in Windows 7 IE 11 with exe downloads without a content disposition.

One solution that others have tried and had success with is appending ‘.exe’ to the url.

`window.location = inInstalLink + "?tempID=" + intRandom + ".exe"`

With dealing with IE compatibility, sometimes solutions aren’t as intuitive or logical as we would like them to be.